Pass dynamic arguments to a related form (no code) - possible?
after searches and tests, I am asking here on what seems to me quite a common scenario but for which I haven't found a way with just core and modules, i.e. without writing code. I am using Drupal 10.2.
Scenario: a content type PARENT and related content type CHILD, where n children are related to 1 parent.
The issue: how to pass dynamically the value of a field in the parent to a field in the child form? For example a field value in the child is a concatenation of the title of the parent with an input string typed by the user in the child form.
What I tried with no success:

created a multi-value reference field in the parent entity pointing to the child entity, enhanced with Inline Entity Form -IEF module to easily create/edit/delete child instances. Issue: the reference field does not support passing arguments nor URL and IEF does not open a new window so I see no way of using the URL to pass arguments.
created a reference field in the child entity pointing to the parent entity (the reverse case than the previous one), created an "Add Child" button on the parent for passing query parameters to the form in the URL, so that in the form the Entity PrePopulate module will retrieve arguments from the URL and put them into the form fields. Issue: how to create the dynamic link in the parent since core fields do not support token nor twig?

Am I missing something easy to accomplish that?
thanks a lot in advance
Giuse

I don't think this is a common scenario. Content types stand on their own. And the scenario you describe requires advanced logic taking following exemplary scenarios (and more) into account: What if the parent's field value changes? What if the parent node gets deleted? What if the child is referenced in multiple parents?

You probably need a different data structure than content types offer. What you describe sounds more like paragraphs and a little bit of custom form alteration or JS. Depends on what exactly you need the child entities for. Just for display? For reverse referencing? For filtering on a global all childs scale?

Thanks, I try to be more specific: the parent entity is PRODUCT, the N children are PRODUCT VARIANT, there N variants per product. I was looking for a way to pass info from the product to the variants so that the variant form is aware of the product it is a child of. Is this not a correct way of using content entitites?
